# How can I "go to edit point" with emmet? because option+control+right arrow is not working

Tags: html, css

I have Dreamweaver CC 7698 build 2015. By reading the manual it seems that it has embedded Emmet v. 1.0, it works, however, when I try to "go to edit point", for example in several li the command that the official webpage state is not working (option+control+right arrow), neither the tab key.

So when I type the key combination in order to navigate between the edit points, it does not work. Next example is what it supposed to do (the * is the edit point or blinking cursor)

li * li 
li * li 
li * li

Hopefully someone will help here. Thanks!